# Why is Pipelight attached to Geary? And how can I disable it?

Tags: pipelight, geary

When I start Geary I get the following output in terminal:

```
user@ubuntu-machine:~$ geary
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_1_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.1.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/user/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using wine prefix directory /home/user/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.1-installer is already installed in '/home/user/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/user/.wine-pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7422a7, 0x7e0120, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x6cf648, (null), (null), 0x7e0120): stub
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] init successful!
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] OpenGL Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] OpenGL Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6570
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] Your GPU is in the restricted whitelist, using limited hardware acceleration.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using thread asynccall event handling.
err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7ea752c4 "lock.c: LOCKTABLEENTRY.crit" wait timed out in thread 002b, blocked by 002a, retrying (60 sec)

(process:5908): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7ea752c4 "lock.c: LOCKTABLEENTRY.crit" wait timed out in thread 0026, blocked by 0023, retrying (60 sec)
```

Sometimes I have to kill and restart Geary several times to get it running. The last error repeats itself every minute.

I don't understand what is causing Pipelight to be attached to it. There's no reason for it. Does somebody know where we can change this behaviour and restrict it to the default browsers?

Comment: Question might be better posed by the pipelight developers - it could be a bug that could be resolved with their product: https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight

Comment: @fossfreedom thx, did that. I will report the solution here.